# span text over the image

Tags: html, css

i am try to dsiplay span text over the image when mouse hover the div.
i am try this.
**html**

```
<div id="some-div">
  <a href="#"><img class='round_border type_border' src='http://www.jewsnews.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Donald_Duck.gif'/>
  <span id="some-element">Dounald
  </span></a>
</div>
```

**css** look like this

```
<style>
    #some-div{  
      position:relative
    }
    #some-element {
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      border: 1px solid orange;
      display: none;
      font-size: 10px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      background:rgba(255,79,50,.5);
      color:Black !important;
      margin-top:2px;
      border:1px solid gray;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    }

    #some-div:hover #some-element {
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      cursor: pointer;
      color:#FFFFFF;
    }
    a{
    position: relative;

    }
    .type_border {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
    position: absolute;
    }
    .round_border {
    float: left;
    border:1px solid gray;
    -webkit-border-radius: 500px;
    -moz-border-radius: 500px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background: white;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want like a tooltip?

Comment: If you want tooltip-like behavior you can use javascript plugins, there are plenty of them.

Answer (score 5):

Add `position: absolute` to `span` and `position:relative` to main `div`

```
#some-div{  
  position:relative
}
#some-element {
  width:80px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: none;
  font-size: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/IGERIqI/2/)**

Comment: Seems to be what the user asked for, +1

Comment: @javid your edited question has no clue about what you need. On a guess I have made some changes look at this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OBameJe/3/)

Comment: @Sowmya i want to sapn text("Donald_Duck") in image center http://jsfiddle.net/jackphp/fewC5/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use Title.

```
<img class='img' title='Donald Duck' src='http://www.jewsnews.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Donald_Duck.gif'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want text to be displayed on mouse hover image.

You can simply do it by using `title` attribute of html image element

For ex:

You will be able to see that text when mouse hoveered.

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as far as i know you cannot insert text on the image.

Workaround for this is to have span in a div which is having background image can work

```
#some-div{
    background-image:url('http://www.jewsnews.co.il/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Donald_Duck.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

check this link  http://jsfiddle.net/sy6MG/